# Why do navaids noted in the chart supplement have a W next to them?

Tags: navaids, chart-supplement

[image]

Why do navaids noted in the chart supplement have a W next to them?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Most VORs are equipped for voice transmission on the VOR frequency. VORs without voice capability are indicated by the letter “W” (without voice) included in the class designator (VORW).”

I assume the same thing applies to VORTACs.

Source: AIM Navigation Aids 1.1-3 VHF Omni-directional Range (VOR)
https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap1_section_1.html

Comment: It applies the same to VORTAC, the VOR portion has no voice channel, the DME portion is not concerned.